# Exception: bus.Bus unavailable Odoo 8 при попытке запустить jobs в magnto-connector

Tags: nginx, magento, odoo

Есть система одоо связаная с магазином Магенто. Для ускорения работы системы надо использовать workers. Если конфигурации нет workers, работник не может открыть больше 4-6 окон в браузере, при чем каждое следующее открывается в 2 раза дольше. Без workers связь с магазином нормальная и обмен данными нормальный. Когда добавляю workers работник можеть открыть намного больше окон, система работает быстрее, но рушится обмен между системой и магазином. (Вариант заставить открывать меньше окон не пройдет :) )
Перелопатил уже все что мог, и пробовал разные варианты решения по двум страницам отсюда 
[>>> поиск Гугла](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Exception%3A%20bus.Bus%20unavailable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=GDUGWbjYCqbi8AfYhIewAQ). Возможно я что то где-то упустил.
Ниже приведены конфиги odoo и nginx

Вот конфиг odoo

```
[options]
        ; This is the password that allows database operations:
        ; admin_passwd = admin
        db_host = False
        db_port = False
        db_maxconn=100
        db_user = odoo
        db_password = False
        addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons,/etc/odoo_addons
        workers = 9
        proxy_mode = True
        limit_memory_hard = 805306368
        limit_memory_soft = 671088640
        limit_request = 8192
        limit_time_cpu = 60
        limit_time_real = 120
        max_cron_threads = 2
        longpolling_port = 8072
        xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
        netrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
```

Вот конфиг nginx

```
upstream odoo8 {
server 127.0.0.1:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream odoo8-im {
server 127.0.0.1:8072 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
}

## http redirects to https ##
server {
listen 80;
server_name _;

# Strict Transport Security
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
# server port and name
listen 443;
server_name _;

# Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
# as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
client_max_body_size 200m;

# add ssl specific settings
keepalive_timeout 60;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;

# limit ciphers
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# increase proxy buffer to handle some OpenERP web requests
proxy_buffers 16 64k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;

#general proxy settings
# force timeouts if the backend dies
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

# set headers
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

# Let the OpenERP web service know that we~@~Yre using HTTPS, otherwise
# it will generate URL using http:// and not https://
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

# by default, do not forward anything
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_buffering off;

location / {
proxy_pass http://odoo8;
}

location /longpolling {
proxy_pass http://odoo8-im;
}
# by default, do not forward anything
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_buffering off;


# cache some static data in memory for 60mins.
# under heavy load this should relieve stress on the OpenERP web interface a bit.
location /web/static/ {
proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
proxy_buffering on;
expires 864000;
proxy_pass http://odoo8;
}
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: возможно, имеет смысл привести директивы `proxy_redirect` и `proxy_buffering` к тому же виду, как и в [документации](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/deploy.html#id7). у вас они упомянуты дважды, в документации же есть только `proxy_redirect` и только в `location /`

Comment: Поискал еще чуток, и нашел, что конектор к магенто тоже требует воркеры. Но, если прописать как написано в доке, одоо вааще не стартует ((( 
http://odoo-connector.com/guides/multiprocessing.html,   а как вы написали попробовал. Не оно (

Comment: типа так WORKER=PathToOpenerp-connector-worker.  
А ниже переписать function _start() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $USER:$USER --background --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON $WORKER -- --config $CONFIG --logfile $LOGFILE
}